# Rails 3, get 500 status code on production environment with no error, and no log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm developing an app using [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) plugin to build a calendar with some events. Everything works fine in development and test environment but when i try to switch to production env trying to open the calendar page the server returns a 500 error page.

What is really weird for me is that event_calendar worked well until today, and i didn't touch a line of code related to this plugin.

So, that's what i made to debug with no success:

- Migrate database and precompile assets on production env.
- Opened log/production.log to find some error, but nothing was there, non error logged.
- Uncomment this line on production.rb `config.log_level = :debug`, still no error logged.
- Modified the index action of Calendar Controller with a dummy empty index action to make sure that was not the problem.
- Opened rails console on production env and try to make a get request to `/calendar`:

  ```
  1.9.3-p0 :001 > app.get '/calendar' 
  => 500 
  1.9.3-p0 :002 > app.response
  => #<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x007ff53607d298 @body=["<!DOCTYPE         html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  ... HTML CODE OF 500 ERROR PAGE ... </html>\n"]
  ,@header={"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length"=>"643", "X-Request-Id"=>"d47e6d869dd8e215a0741430ee2eacae", "X-Runtime"=>"0.036510"}, @status=500, @sending_file=false, @blank=false, @content_type=text/html, @charset="utf-8", @cache_control={}, @etag=nil>
  ```

Apart from this everything works fine, even in production env. So i guess the issue depends on something wrong on event_calendar but i think the problem of ghost error is more general.
I really hope that error is somewhere!
Hope someone can help me! Thanks

Marco